What tests or methods does Biblical Hermeneutics apply to chapter headings?
This isn't a question about why are there chapter headings, should there be chapter headings, what is the history of chapter headings, or "are chapter headings a sort of iota?"
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chapters_and_verses_of_the_Bible#Christian_versions
On those topics, the information on wikipedia has seemed ample to my needs (although the part I need them from has very few references, and any book recommendations are hugely appreciated)
The question is what tests or methods does Biblical Hermeneutics apply to chapter headings in the translations and editions that admit of them, and with particular regard to how they should be worded?
With the best will in the world, one can see that testing might not have historically-actually taken place, and that (for argument's sake) a centuries-old tradition of titling Mark 5 as "Jesus Restores a Demon-Possessed Man" (NIV) or "Jesus Heals a Man with a Demon" (ESV) might struggle to be overturned by a hermeneutic objection that it spoils the surprise in Mark 5:15 (which is the first time the Greek term δαίμων appears).
It might do to discuss this example, but without descending into a Word Study of what δαίμων or πνεύματα τὰ ἀκάθαρτα signify. Or indicate. Or say. Or mean. Etc.
My approach would be that if this contention was made, and didn't stand, then it should be recorded that it didn't stand (and why and in what forms), which I hope is approaching the spirit of "show your workings"
And it might be interesting to know a little of how publishers and presses do go about this in the real world. One can easily imagine traditions in which a proposed chapter-heading is carried down stone corridors, and recited, and then blessed in triplicate, and others where it is brainstormed - but also there may be specific inventions of benefit to exegesis and translation generally. It can happen that scribes' and scholiasts' notes and chapter headings have sometimes become mistaken for a text, and would hazard that in our modern age we have invented little that makes the readers of future millennia more proof against these mistakes than we have been.
Perhaps does copyright apply? With some horror one imagines publishers jealously guarding the precise wording of their chapter headers, and mentally counting each time they find someone unwittingly pasting them to the internet.
I beg leave to exclude the Psalms or any points in the scripture where sometimes it is controversial whether in antiquity something like headings may have become part of the scripture their having been inspired. Well, there might be valuable points to be drawn from the techniques applied in such situations, and those who know of them will know how to describe that in a respectful and collegiate way.
When the marketing team wants a gloss for "John the Baptist Beheaded", what sorts of things does the exegete ask of the text? And the heading.
EDIT (08/08/2024)
Thinking further on the understanding of chapter headings as just interpretation. What is (currently) done versus these?:-

Headings steering the reading e.g. Mk.12:28 "Jesus' theory of ethics"

Headings being longer than the passages

Headings that future readers/scribes/optical recognizers of characters/machines-for-large-languages/etc might blend with the text. e.g. if they read some edition of NIV as You are badly mistaken about the Greatest Commandment



Chapter headings are not part of the Bible text but were added in very modern times by editors and publishers to aid the reader.

Chapter/section headings are just interpretations. They can be evaluated like any other interpretation of a Bible passage.

@ curiousdannii - when the interpretations are completed and inserted into the text (or at least into gaps in it), are they an acceptable form of eisegesis, or not eisegesis?

@FelixLXX asks "are [interpretations] an acceptable form of eisegesis", and "what tests or methods does Biblical Hermeneutics apply to chapter headings".  I'm having trouble understanding what those questions actually mean. E.g. a chapter heading might have been written ten years ago, so why would anyone "apply hermeneutics" to it when they could simply ask the author?

@FelixLXX, you could include real examples of chapter headings and how one might "apply hermeneutics" to them.

@RayButterworth - after some time's having passed isn't hermeneutics needed for the incipits? https://www.titusinstitute.com/jesusevidences/manuscriptevidence.php where an informational heading is evidence of authorship. I mentioned Mark 5 - where NIV have "Jesus Restores a Demon-Possessed Man" in preference to "Jesus Restores a Man with an Impure Spirit" So I suppose they interpreted from holistic hindsight and the question is why do they say they do that.

I've tried to put it as quite an open question - if it's outside the discipline's domain and someone just says what happens in the chapter that's a fine answer for me. People excavating NIVs from car glove compartments in the year 8510, printed on the thinnest possible paper, are not asking.

@FelixLXX, By "What tests or methods does Biblical Hermeneutics apply to …", do you mean "What hermeneutical methods do people apply to …*"?  If not, I've no idea what it means.

yes I think so. A 'test' would just be something like if they check the heading doesn't nudge the reader into a misreading. And I've no idea what's to be capitalized or not sorry if it signified something and I'm happy to change the question title

@FelixLXX. So are you really asking what hermeneutical methods are used by the people that write the chapter titles?

yes - but I didn't know if it's the same people or if that writing is done separately afterwards and they consult back to an expert. I guess it would be the checking of it more than the writing of it. And I guess published bibles do get subjected to critical review from outside - which might see fit to mention poor or neat chapter headings. Otherwise I guess there wouldn't be editions with and without them.

Q: What tests or methods does Biblical Hermeneutics apply to chapter headings in the translations and editions that admit of them? (I'll answer this part as it seems the least opinion based)
Short Answer: Nothing. Hermeneutics is focused on the text itself not the additional elements like chapter headings. These headings were added later by translators to help organize and divide the Bible into easier-to-digest pieces. They are not part of the original text and thus are not subjected to the same rigorous hermeneutic analysis as the text itself. If anything, one should use hermeneutics to create the headings.
Biblical scholars spend a lot of time studying the original languages (Hebrew, Aramaic, Greek), as well as the history and culture of the biblical world. They use textual criticism, historical criticism, and literary criticism, to help them understand the scripture as intended.
What is Hermeneutics: [2]

Hermeneutics describes the task of explaining the  meaning of the
Scriptures. The word derives from  the Greek verb hermeneuein that
means “to explain,  interpret or to translate,” while the noun
hermeneia  means “interpretation” or “translation.”

A blog on Bible Gateway touches on chapter headings:

With the exception of the titles in Psalms, the Bible’s authors didn’t
write their books of Bible with chapter or section headings in mind.
They were added later by translators in order to help organize and divide the Bible into easier to digest pieces.

Headings vary:

Genesis 1 begins with the heading: “The beginning” in the New
International Version 1984 translation
“The Account of Creation” in the New Living Translation
There’s no header at all in the King James Version.

Copyright: I'll briefly note. While the original biblical texts are in the public domain, certain "self" translations, annotations, chapter introductions, and yes, even chapter headings, can be copyrighted if they involve a significant amount of original work.
In conclusion, biblical hermeneutics does not directly deal with added chapter headings. However, the principles of faithful and accurate representation of the original text should still apply. The headings should serve to aid understanding without unduly influencing interpretation.

I've found this very clear thank you

@FelixLXX Absolutely! Your addition to the site is welcomed. I look forward to seeing more.
